# How to not write float if not initialized with Gson (GsonBuilder())

Tags: java, gson

My POJO:

```
public class MyObj{
    String index;
    float spread;
}
```

My generator:

```
MyObj stub = new MyObj();
stub.setIndex("1234");
// stub.setSpread(0.20f);
```

My to toString method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapter(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeAdapter().nullSafe()).create().toJson(this);
}
```

My JSON result is:

```
{
    "index": "1234",
    "spread": 0.0
}
```

but I want:

```
{
    "index": "1234"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSon default settings foresee the `null` property will not show up in the resulting JSON. If you want to see explicitly the value, you have to use `.serializeNulls()`.
But in you case you have a `float` value (primitive data type), that for default is initialized to `0` even if you don't set it explicitly. So you must define you class with a Float value instead:

> ```
> public class MyObj{
>     String index;
>     Float spread;
> }
> ```

So the "spread" field will not appear in Json serialization, since it is initialized to `null` for default.

Comment: Same as linked possible-duplicate answer.